# Searching for webpages within a website by keyword

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

Is there a way in rvest() to search for webpages within a given website that contain a keyword?

For example, given the url http://umich.edu/, can I return a list of contained webpages that have the word "faculty"?

I'm fairly new to rvest as well as web scraping so I'm unsure how to approach this kind of problem. Thank you so much!

Edit: I'm looking for links to the **pages** that contain the word "faculty"

Comment: Are you looking for the links that contain the word "faculty" in their names or are you actually looking for ***the links to the pages*** that contain the word "faculty"?

Comment: The latter, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating functions that get all the links in the main page and check if any of them contains the word "faculty". Below is a simple script that can constitute a decent starting:

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)

# Define function to get all the links in the main page (except for social media sites)

get_all_links <- function(URL) {
  links <- URL %>% read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//a") %>%
    html_attr("href")
  # Remove links starting with # or those that only contain /
  links <- links[!(links == "/" | grepl("#", links))]
  # Remove social media sites (Linkedin, Facebook, Twitter, etc.)
  social_media <- "facebook|linkedin|twitter|instagram|pinterest|youtube"
  links <- links[!(grepl(social_media, links, ignore.case = TRUE))]

  # Return links (prepended with main url if they are relative links)
  ifelse(startsWith(links, "http"), links, paste0(URL,links))
}



# Define function to check if a link's page contains the word "faculty"

is_faculty_link <- function(URL) {
  # Use a user agent to identify your crawler
  URL <- curl(URL, handle = new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))
  # Get the content of the page
  page_content <- URL %>% read_html() %>%
    html_text()
  # Check if the page contains the word faculty (regardless of case sensitivity)
  return(grepl("faculty", page_content, ignore.case = TRUE))
}
```

#### Usage:

```
michigan_url <- "http://umich.edu"
michigan_links <- get_all_links(michigan_url)
faculty_links <- unlist(lapply(michigan_links, is_faculty_link))
faculty_links <- michigan_links[faculty_links]
```

#### Output:

```
 [1] "https://email.med.umich.edu"                                                                                    
 [2] "http://mirlyn.lib.umich.edu"                                                                                    
 [3] "http://campusinfo.umich.edu/mapsAndDirections"                                                                  
 [4] "http://umich.edu/schools-colleges/"                                                                             
 [5] "https://wolverineaccess.umich.edu"                                                                              
 [6] "http://umich.edu/prospective-students/"                                                                         
 [7] "http://umich.edu/current-students/"                                                                             
 [8] "http://umich.edu/faculty-staff/"                                                                                
 [9] "http://umich.edu/parents/"                                                                                      
[10] "http://umich.edu/alumni/"                                                                                       
[11] "http://umich.edu/about/"                                                                                        
[12] "http://umich.edu/academics/"                                                                                    
[13] "http://umich.edu/life-at-michigan/"                                                                             
[14] "http://umich.edu/athletics/"                                                                                    
[15] "http://umich.edu/research/"                                                                                     
[16] "http://umich.edu/health-medicine/"                                                                              
[17] "http://umich.edu/initiatives/"                                                                                  
[18] "http://umich.edu/giving/"                                                                                       
[19] "http://diversity.umich.edu/?features=see-the-video-recap-of-u-ms-historic-diversity-equity-and-inclusion-launch"
[20] "http://www.engin.umich.edu/college/about/news/stories/2016/september/wringing-power-from-water"                 
[21] "http://umich.edu/schools-colleges/"                                                                             
[22] "http://admissions.umich.edu/academics-majors/majors-degrees"                                                    
[23] "http://record.umich.edu/articles/us-news-releases-its-latest-graduate-program-rankings"                         
[24] "http://global.umich.edu/"                                                                                       
[25] "http://record.umich.edu/articles/special-alumni-award-helps-highlight-u-ms-past-herald-its-future"              
[26] "https://lsa.umich.edu/lsa/news-events/all-news/search-news/starslaughter.html"                                  
[27] "http://umdearborn.edu/"                                                                                         
[28] "http://umflint.edu/"                                                                                            
[29] "http://umich.edu/contact/"                                                                                      
[30] "http://obp.umich.edu/root/budget/state-required-reports/"
```